# whats the difference between an object and string object

Tags: apache-flex, object

I think i am lost with basics itself. What is the difference between these two. String object is an instance of String Class.

```
var guru:Object = new Object();

var guru:String = new String();
```

Comment: the question is so basic it doesn't make sense ;) I'd suggest reading an OOP book.

Comment: Why the Java tag? Your code isn't.

Comment: I knew it i want to read an OOP book, but want to know to from some people here who can slam me with ripostes.

Comment: The reason of Java tag is that its a question which is of basic so that anyone can explain

Comment: @theband: Yes, but java programmers are not like actionscript 3 programmers. Also, go learn a OOP book, It's like asking the difference between a elephant and a mouse.

Comment: A very great answer mate, but we in actionscript have datatype called Object which made me confusing and i was expecting a riposte from other programmers too who code in different language

Comment: @M28 - More like the difference between an elephant and a mammel ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object is a basic object. It has very few intrinsic properties and methods. [More detail here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html)

A string is an extended object that has the properties and methods relevant to strings. [More detail here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're really not sure, I'd suggest looking up the answer here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_11.html

Briefly, it states:

> **String data type**
>
> The String data type represents a
>   sequence of 16-bit characters. Strings
>   are stored internally as Unicode
>   characters, using the UTF-16 format.
>   Strings are immutable values, just as
>   they are in the Java programming
>   language. An operation on a String
>   value returns a new instance of the
>   string. The default value for a
>   variable declared with the String data
>   type is null. The value null is not
>   the same as the empty string (""),
>   even though they both represent the
>   absence of any characters.
>
> **Object data type**
>
> The Object data type is defined by the
>   Object class. The Object class serves
>   as the base class for all class
>   definitions in ActionScript. The
>   ActionScript 3.0 version of the Object
>   data type differs from that of
>   previous versions in three ways.
>   First, the Object data type is no
>   longer the default data type assigned
>   to variables with no type annotation.
>   Second, the Object data type no longer
>   includes the value undefined, which
>   used to be the default value of Object
>   instances. Third, in ActionScript 3.0,
>   the default value for instances of the
>   Object class is null.

If that doesn't satisfy your question, you're going to have to get more specific.

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html) can help you with basic Object Oriented questions regarding ActionScript 3.

[The reference guide for `String`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/String.html) states that `String` inherits directly from `Object`.

The `String` class provides a bunch of useful methods that help with string manipulation on top of the few methods that `Object` provides (like `toString()`).